# Best practice inserting Child in Doctrine without loading parent

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a database schema which consists of a Parent with n Childs.
Now I want to insert a new child without loading the parent, so I dont have to perform an additional DB call.
What is the best (most Doctrine like) way to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DocumentManager::getReference`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/2.4.x/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentManager.php#L604-L619) will create an uninitialized proxy object for you. You can use that proxy object freely in your `Child` class, persist and flush will work normally.